# Rate conversion to USD or EUR

Tags: ms-access, combobox

I'm working on a form that, after using a combobox (possible values are only EURO or USD), show the cost in the selected currency. Within my **qry_costes** I have all costs in local currency. I also have a second table **RateToEUR** with the conversion from several currencies to EURO, and a third one **RateToUSD** doing the same to USD. The idea is that, after using the combobox embedded in a form, field qry_costes.cost from **qry_costes** will be multiplied by the properly rate. I mean, if EURO is selected, and qry_costes.currency is BRL, for example, then qry_costes.cost will by multiplied by the value that belongs to BRL within RateToEUR. The problem is that I don't know how to distinguish between RateToEUR from RateToUSD. Is possible to use a IFF clause? 
Thanks all for your help.

Comment: Hi again, sorry for raising a question with any attempt. I've tried below:
SELECT U.cost, U.currency, exRate_USD.conversion*U.cost AS USD_cost, exRate_EUR.conversion*U.cost AS EUR_cost
FROM (( TableU AS U LEFT JOIN exRate AS exRate_USD ON (U.currency = exRate_USD.currency_from AND exRate_USD.currency_to = 'USD')) LEFT JOIN exRate AS exRate_EUR ON (U.currency = exRate_EUR.currency from AND exRate_EUR.currency_to = 'EUR')

exRate contains: currency_from, currency_to, conversion fields. 

What I'm trying is when currency from U is EUR, the cost is multiplied by the relevant conversion

Comment: above code do the conversion, but the query only fill cost and EUR_cost OR USD_cost, no all fields. I mean, if currency is in EUR, ok, code shall convert to USD and fill the EUR_cost with the same EUR value.. any idea? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've found that exRate table was wrong, but code is ok. Thanks anyway